# nullpointerexception using arrayadapter

Tags: android-listview, nullpointerexception

I get null pointer exception when I use arrayadapter.

The error says

"at android.widget.arrayadapter.getcount
 at android.widget.listview.setAdapter"

I don't know why I get this error.

I will simplify my codes.

Please let me know why I get this error.

public class ChapterDisease extends Activity

```
 implements OnItemClickListener,
        OnItemLongClickListener {

    /* Setting Database */
    SQLiteDatabase db = MainActivity.db;
    Cursor cursor;

    /* Initializing */
    ListView listview;
    /* Get the chapter disease list */
    ArrayList<Disease> diseaseList;
    /* The list to show the disease names in the activity UI */
    ArrayList<String> diseaseNamesList;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ChapterDiseaseAdapter rowAdapter = null;
```

I declare listview and arraylist.

My adapter is row Adapter and ChapterDiseaseAdapter is inner class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

rowAdapter = new ChapterDiseaseAdapter();

listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chap_listView);
        listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        System.out.println("size of diseaseNamesList ="+diseaseNamesList.size());
        listview.setAdapter(rowAdapter);
```

This is the onCreate.

I tried to print the size of Array. and It is 21, not 0.

```
    class ChapterDiseaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        ChapterDiseaseAdapter() {
            super(ChapterDisease.this,
                    R.layout.activity_chapter_disease_row,diseaseNamesList);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null)
                convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            View row = convertView; 
            DiseaseHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chapter_disease_row,
                        parent, false);
                holder = new DiseaseHolder(row, order++);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (DiseaseHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            holder.populateFrom(diseaseNamesList.get(position));

            return (row);
        }
    }

    // This class is the holder of listview1
    class DiseaseHolder {

        private ImageView imgView = null;
        private TextView txt = null;
        private TextView level = null;
        private ImageView icon = null;

        private CheckBox check = null;

        DiseaseHolder(View row, int order) {
            imgView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.chapter_disease_row_img);

            txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chapter_disease_row_txt);


        }

        void populateFrom(String d) {
            imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico1);
            txt.setText(d);
//          name.setText(r.getMonster().getMonsterName());
//          level.setText("" + r.getMonster().getMonsterLevel());
//          icon.setImageResource(r.getMonster().getImgMarker());

        }
    }
}
```

Last is the inner class.

Comment: I got to know why!

I didn't do 

diseaseNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

on the onCreate.

I transformed existing code, and it didn't need this one.

But I needed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting this error because in your `ChapterDiseaseAdapter` class the `diseaseNamesList` object is null as you haven't passed it to the adapter via. the constructor. Also you need to pass the activity context to the adapter.

Firstly in your onCreate method:

```
rowAdapter = new ChapterDiseaseAdapter(this, diseaseNamesList);
```

Then in ChapterDiseaseAdapter.java:

```
ChapterDiseaseAdapter(Context context, List<String> diseaseNamesList) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_chapter_disease_row, diseaseNamesList);
}
```